# swagger ui integration with maven project not displaying APIs

Tags: java, maven, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I have an existing maven project with REST APIs. I am trying to integrate Swagger with the project. When I run the project, I get the empty Swagger UI page. No APIs are loaded. Where am I going wrong?

pom.xml

```
<!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using a custom Application class(not web.xml)

```
public class MyRestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
public MyRestApplication() {
    System.out.println("Entering Custom Application");
    property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);    
    property(ServerProperties.
    BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);
    register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);        
    register(StorageResource.class);
    register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);        
}
}
```

In my StorageResource file:

```
@Api(value = "/Person")
@Path("")
public class StorageResource {
static Logger logger = 
Logger.getLogger(StorageResource.class.getName());
@PUT
@Path("/person-manager-resource/addPerson")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@ApiOperation(
        value = "method api",
        notes = "method api notes"
)
public Object addPerson(String reqBody) {
    AddPerson add = new AddPerson();
    return add.addPerson(reqBody);
}
}
```

In the index.html of Swagger UI(copied from **dist** folder to webapp folder)

```
window.onload = function() {  
// Build a system
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
url: "http://localhost:8080/demographics/dgs/swagger.json",
dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
presets: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
  SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
],
plugins: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
],
layout: "StandaloneLayout"
})
window.ui = ui
}
```

My web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>in.healthelife.DGS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>in.healthelife.DGS.data.MyRestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dgs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I see `beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources");` just to check, is `StorageResource` somewhere in this package `io.swagger.resources`?

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to swagger. The StorageResource is in package "in.healthelife.DGS.resources".

Comment: Did this resolve it or do you still have the problem?

Comment: Still having the problem. Maybe something to do with the url?

Comment: please don't edit original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update2**
I dont understand why you have used 2 `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` it will not work

make sure your are mentioning your custom application is loaded through jersey container by mentioning it in web.xml

like shown below

---

```
swagger-jersey2-jaxrs
```

dependency will be enough rest will be pulled transitively . i don't know which version of jersey you are using but you have to extend `ResourceConfig` in order to customize the application not `Application` class itself

You have to register these 2 features in your extended resource config

```
io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource,
     io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers
```

And your custom application class has to be mentioned in your web.xml like so

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
   </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.foo.app.CustomApplication
     </param-value>
    </init-param>
    </servlet>
```

**Update**

```
url: "http://localhost:8080/OpenEMPIStorage/rest/api-docs",
```

its best that this is relative path of swagger.json so it should be like this

```
 url: "swagger.json"
```

and make sure the json you are getting in in path `http://localhost:8080/OpenEMPIStorage/rest/api-docs` is copied in this swagger.json file

and your code inside Resource Config should be like

```
public MyRestApplication() 
{

    System.out.println("Entering Custom Application");

    property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
    // @ValidateOnExecution annotations on subclasses won't cause errors.
    property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);
    register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    register(AuthenticationFilter.class);
    register(AuthenticationResponseFilter.class);
 }
```

don't use `@ApplicationPath`

your Swagger.json should be available under fallowing path

```
http://<ip address:portname or domain name >/<yourapp-path>/dgs/swagger.json
```

Comment: If I don't extend Application class, then where will I add resources? The getClasses method is coming from Application itself.

Comment: ResourceConfig is sub class of Application refer Documentation properly

Comment: I have made the necessary changes. Please have a look. Its still not working.

Comment: Now? I made changes in web.xml and MyRestApplication class.

Comment: I seriously need help.

Comment: this is all i can help

Comment: AuthenticationFilter.class and AuthenticationResponseFilter.class are giving errors

Comment: I have edited the question just now. Made the necessary changes and now swagger.json file is getting generated under the url : "http://localhost:8080/demographics/dgs/swagger.json"

Comment: But I am still not getting anything in Swagger UI index.html page

Comment: please don't edit original question . readers can not know the difference before and after .